# How to unchange the html form content after window.location using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html.dropdownlistfor, window.location

I am having one html form which contains a drop down list with two options, one is public and another is private.If I select the private option from the list, I will show one `TextBox` for adding a contact and if I select public ,i will hide that TextBox.The problem is when I am selecting public option it will hide the TextBox while when I am selecting private its shows me the TextBox.After clicking on textbox, I am navigating to other page for selecting contact and appending that to the contact in the same TextBox.but when I am coming back to the same html page again,in drop down list again, that is set to public and that TextBox is hidden.
This is my post.html code :

```
<select id="privacy"  onchange="main()">
    <option value="public">public</option>`
    <option value="private">private</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="choose contacts" id="to" onclick="window.location='contact.html';"/>
```

and here is my javascript code :

```
function main(){
    var contact = "";
    if ( sessionStorage.getItem("contact") ) {
        contact = sessionStorage.getItem("contact");

        $("#to").val(contact);


    }

    var select = document.getElementById("privacy");
    var select1 = document.getElementById("privacy").value;
    if(select1==="private")
    {

        $("#to").show();

        }
    if(select1==="public")
    {

        $("#to").hide();
    }
    var value1 = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    if(value1==="private")
    {

        $("#to").show();

    }
    if(value1==="public")
    {

        $("#to").hide();
    }

}
```

This problem is in post.html when i am selecting private option and when i am clicking on the tetbox i am going to contact.html.after adding contact

```
var contact = "";
        if ( sessionStorage.getItem("contact") ) {
            contact = sessionStorage.getItem("contact");

            $("#to").val(contact);


        }
```

i am comming back to the same post.html but what i am seeing here again in the select box the public option is selected and that textbox also hidden.this is beacuse
 of window.location=post.html from contact.html.So again its loading the DOM newly.So no matter whatever I had selected using drop down list, its gets vanished.so is there any solution such that after selcting value and comming back to the post.html whatever select option i was selected it should remain same after comming from contact.html?

Need some guidance here. Thanks.

Comment: Please correct the syntax near $("#to.show()

Comment: yes, Your syntax is wrong `$("#to.show();}if(select1==="public"){$("#to").hide();}` Please correct it. Also, you can't use `value="choose privacy"` inside the `select option`. It's not valid `HTML` Please correct all. Then we can find a solution. Also, Tell us what do you want to do actual.

Comment: You can check this [TRY THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/5Tj9b/)

Comment: no...still same output..as i was getting before..